# How to wait for website to load new components after clickin add 10 to website

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have problem beacuse I want wait with my second function and louch it only after all components loads on website. In function val I'm clicking button to show more content and there I want to wait.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
      '--no-sandbox',
      '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      '--window-size=1600,1200',
    ],
    defaultViewport: null,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(
    'https://www.gelbeseiten.de/suche/friseur/bundesweit?umkreis=4000',
    {
      waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
    }
  );

  async function getData() {
    return await page.evaluate(function () {
      const value = document.getElementById('mod-TrefferlisteInfo').innerText;
      function val() {
        for (var i = 50; i < 49951; i += 10) {
          document.getElementById('mod-LoadMore--button').click();
        }
      }

      function second() {
        val();
        function getData() {
          const liTag = document.querySelectorAll(
            '.mod-AdresseKompakt__phoneNumber'
          );
          let data = [];
          liTag.forEach((number) => {
            data.push(number.innerText);
          });
          return data;
        }
        return getData();
      }
      return second();
    });
  }
  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('data.csv');
  writeStream.write(`id, phone number\n`);
  await getData();
  setTimeout(async () => {
    const value = await getData();
    for (i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
      writeStream.write(`${i},${value[i]},\n`);
    }
  }, 600000);
})();
```

I was tring with `DOMContentLoaded` and `window.onload` but this doesn't work. I don't know I need wait for their api to end job?

Comment: You can't access Node-defined variables from inside `evaluate`. That runs in a totally different process. There's no need for so many abstractions here--I think they're leading to confusion. I don't see the need for a write stream either--the data is there in memory so you can dump it all to disk with a single `fs.writeFile` call. Try not to mix promises and callbacks--use the promise version of `setTimeout` if you want to sleep, but try not to sleep in general--use event-driven programming. Any significance to the `49951` number? What is the expected output? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Number `49951` is maximum number of divs with data awaliable to see on page. I want to output array with 49951 elements without `setTimeout`  becuse it was working well with smaller arrays but now I don't know how much time it take for website to show all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I'd avoid premature abstractions until you have correctness established. Breaking out functions too soon makes it harder to debug and understand code, particularly if you're new to async programming.

Secondly, this is a huge amount of data, so it'll take a long time to get to 50k counting 10 records at a time. I don't see an obvious way around it, but feel free to try the below code:

```js
const fs = require("node:fs/promises");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.6.3

const url = "https://www.gelbeseiten.de/suche/friseur/bundesweit?umkreis=4000";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  const allowed = [
    url,
    "https://wwa.wipe.de/wwa.js",
    "https://www.gelbeseiten.de/ajaxsuche",
    "https://www.gelbeseiten.de/webgs/js/trefferliste_below.js?1676928398396",
  ];
  page.on("request", req => {
    allowed.includes(req.url()) ? req.continue() : req.abort();
  });
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const btn = await page.waitForSelector("#mod-LoadMore--button");
  const sel = ".mod-AdresseKompakt__phoneNumber";

  for (;;) {
    const length = (await page.$$(sel)).length;
    await page.$eval("#mod-LoadMore--button", el => el.click());

    try {
      await page.waitForFunction(
        `document.querySelectorAll("${sel}").length !== ${length}`,
        {polling: "mutation", timeout: 10_000}
      );
    }
    catch (err) {}
  }

  const data = await page.$$eval(sel, els => els.map(e => e.textContent));
  await fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(data));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

You can change the loop to `for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {}` to get the first few chunks for testing purposes.

Since 50k elements on screen would likely be slow, another approach is to remove elements you've already scraped, and optionally write to disk.

```js
const url = "https://www.gelbeseiten.de/suche/friseur/bundesweit?umkreis=4000";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  const allowed = [
    url,
    "https://wwa.wipe.de/wwa.js",
    "https://www.gelbeseiten.de/ajaxsuche",
    "https://www.gelbeseiten.de/webgs/js/trefferliste_below.js?1676928398396",
  ];
  page.on("request", req => {
    allowed.includes(req.url()) ? req.continue() : req.abort();
  });
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const btn = await page.waitForSelector("#mod-LoadMore--button");
  const sel = ".mod-AdresseKompakt__phoneNumber";

  for (;;) {
    const length = (await page.$$(sel)).length;
    await page.$eval("#mod-LoadMore--button", el => el.click());

    try {
      await page.waitForFunction(
        `document.querySelectorAll("${sel}").length !== ${length}`,
        {polling: "mutation", timeout: 10_000}
      );
    }
    catch (err) {}
  }

  const data = await page.$$eval(sel, els => els.map(e => e.textContent));
  await fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(data));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

I'm writing to JSON since JS doesn't seem to have a native CSV writer, but it's a cosmetic change. Better to use a library like [PapaParse](https://www.papaparse.com/) than rolling it yourself with string templates. If any of the data unexpectedly has a comma in it, your CSV will be invalid.

I haven't verified these scripts completely, and the `remove()` version is missing a bit of data at the start, but hopefully they'll give you something to work from. I'll revisit this if I have time.

Comment: Thank you so much first option of code is working for me. Now i will try understand all things wich are there and learn how to improve code in future <3